# Drupal 7 DropDown select list to show in block of view

Tags: drop-down-menu, drupal-7, drupal-views

[image]i have created a view block in drupal 7. i want to show a dropdown on the block.
What i have done is tried making a content type of type form, having a field made for the dropdown. Now, without adding content, it shows nothing in the auto preview.
i need to show the dropdown in the view.
What can i do?

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation is poor, but I'll try to give you a possible solution from what I understood.

If you want a dropdown in a view you are talking about exposed filters. Edit the view and go to the filter section and add a filter (a filter of field city in your case), then edit the filter and check "Expose these filter to users" (or something like that), check the options to your like and SAVE the view (some people forget to save the view).

Hope that helps!